# Can I do "string contains" in a WiX if statement?

Tags: wix, preprocessor

Can I do the following and see if the configuration contains the word "Extra":

```
<?if $(var.MyProject.Configuration) >< "Extra" ?>
```

[This link](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/quot-String-contains-quot-operator-in-Wix-td1401322.html) suggests I can use >< but it doesn't work for me. It compiles with this error:

```
error CNDL0162: An illegal number was found in the expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: not without writing a preprocessor extension.

The link you provided discusses MSI expressions. The [WiX preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) is slightly different and doesn't have the [substring operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or bitwise numeric operators for that matter).